# PHP - I echo out an h1 with a name that I can trigger it with later but it says it is not defined

Tags: php, html

guys!
I just started learning PHP and I've run into a problem. I want to make something display based on what your BMI is and I don't know how to do that. It says that 'bmi' is not defined. I tried avoiding that by creating a button but with the same result. Please help!
``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height">
        <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];
        $weight = $_POST['weight'];
        $height = $_POST['height'];

        function group() {
            $bmi = $_POST['bmi'];
            switch ($bmi) {
                case $bmi <= 20:
                    echo '<h2>below</h2>';
                break;
                case $bmi > 20:
                    echo '<h2>above</h2>';
                break;
            }
        }
        
        echo '<h1 name="bmi">Your BMI is '.round($weight / $height ** 2 * 10000, 2).'</h1>';
        echo '<button name="groupSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">See in which group you fall</button>';

        if (isset($groupSubmit)) {
            $groupSubmit = $_POST['groupSubmit'];
            group();
        }
    }
   
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't just add the attribute `name` on any HTML element and expect it to be submitted with the form. Only actual form elements (like inputs, selects, buttons, textareas) will be submitted with a form. If you want that data to be passed along, you need to add it to a hidden input as well.

Comment: You're also echoing both the h1 and the button  (groupSubmit) outside of a form, which means that button won't do anything, there's nothing for it to submit.

Comment: How do I make It display something if bmi is < 20 and something else if it is > 20, it doesn't need to be with a separate button, they can both appear on the first click on the calculate button but I just didn't figure it out. Please tell me how to do is, you get the concept I just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out already - neither `bmi` nor `groupSubmit` were located in the form and one was not even a form element. An easy solution would be to have a secondary form that you use to calculate the `group` into which the user falls.

As with the original code the 2nd form becomes available when the first form is submitted  - and to avoid complications takes the width/height values as input in addition to the calculated BMI which WILL be available when this 2nd form is posted. The value of this is used as a input argument to the `group` function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='bmicalc' method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height">
            <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <?php
        
            function group($bmi=0) {
                switch( $bmi ) {
                    case $bmi <= 20:
                        echo '<h2>Below</h2>';
                    break;
                    case $bmi > 20:
                        echo '<h2>Above</h2>';
                    break;
                }
            }
                
                
            if( isset( 
                $_POST['weight'],
                $_POST['height']
            )) {
                
                $weight = $_POST['weight'];
                $height = $_POST['height'];
                $bmicalc= round( $weight / $height ** 2 * 10000, 2 );
                
                

                
                printf(
                    '<form method="post">
                        <h1>Your BMI is %1$s</h1>
                        <button name="groupSubmit" type="submit">See in which group you fall</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bmi" value="%1$s" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="height" value="%2$s" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="%3$s" />
                    </form>',
                    $bmicalc,
                    $height,
                    $weight
                );
                
                
                
                if( isset( $_POST['groupSubmit'] ) ) {
                    group( $_POST['bmi'] );
                }
            }
       
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just have one more question - what is %1$s, %2$s ect.

Comment: take a look in the manual at `printf` and `sprintf` - these are placeholders for particular variables

Comment: @ToniKaramanliev - If this answer solved your issue, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so others know it's been resolved and to give the user who helped you their well deserved rep.